# How to store dynamic attributes in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to store and query different attributes per document. Something like this:

JSON:

```
{
    name: "doc1",
    metadata: [
        { color: "red" },
        { data: [ "value1", "value2", "value3" ] },
        { size: 500 },
        { avail: true },
    ]
},
...
{
    name: "doc4980",
    metadata: [
        { otherValues: [ 55, 33 ] },
        { important: true },
    ]
}
```

The keys and values will be different for lots of documents, as they will be defined by the user whenever a new attribute is needed.

Is the following structure (example for the 2nd object only) the best to store this in elasticsearch? (Instead of the attribute names I'd like use mongodb ids which may refer to more details like the user who added the attribute)

```
"_source" : {
    "name": "doc4980",
    "metadata":[
        {
            k: "51d69d8f0c62690000000011", 
            v: [ 55, 33 ]
        },
        {
            k: "51d69d8f0c62690000000016", 
            v: true
        }
    ]
}
```

To avoid cross object matches I would use the following mapping:

```
{
    "my_type" : {
        "properties" : {
            "metadata" : {             
                "type" : "nested"            
            }, 
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: did you ever discover the answer to your question, @joafeldmann?

Comment: I ended up with a mapping like the following:
https://gist.github.com/joafeldmann/f1deb5fc7bd43384472e

Which works out ok so far. It was also further discussed here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/elasticsearch/pUg9GbDOMf8/kJrM4Iv52q0J

But I suggest to double check, if you really need a dynamic structure, cause the complexity ranges through the hole system.

Comment: thanks.. i'm trying to find alternative solutions, but it seems like my limiting factor is that the business req may be that users can define their own column names on a data table. Other solns explored: provide a enumerated set of possible column names and index against that (e.g. real col name: column_1, column_2, ..). But the limiter here is 1. every doc/record would be indexed against n number of column_X, and so 2. i would have to set a max number of possible columns. If you have any thoughts let me know, thanks!

Comment: using a fixed set of fields, would probably make performance better and querying more easily, since you won't need nested queries. So if you can limit fields to e.g. 3 text fields, 3 integers fields an so on, this could be a better solution.